# Help with awkward transition strip between tile and carpet

Tags: tile, carpet, transition

I would like to replace carpet in a hallway with tile.   The carpet extends into multiple living spaces.  I can do all the transition strips except for one that has me flummoxed.

The transition strip must somehow navigate the base of a wrought iron railing system and the top of a stairwell.

Here are some pictures:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's a diagram:

[image]

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: will the stairwell be tile or carpet? You can always bring the transition back to the wall and have the top of the stairwell be carpet still

Comment: The stairs will remain carpeted for now.   I think I understand...leave a foot or a few inches of carpet on landing before the stairs?   I hadn't thought of that...but that's part of the worn carpet I want to replace.   Good thought though!

Comment: All the way back to the corner of the wall for the transition for the cleanest look. You could always patch a square using some of the carpet from the hallway if that area is less worn

Comment: The wall isn't the problem, it's getting the tiles to the stairs and under/around/through the railing base.  Also, a strip of carpet in front of the stairs could be a tripping hazard.